# Retrieve website DOM via http request in GO

Tags: javascript, html, go

in GO I use HTTP request to get a site html and I see in some elements difference than when using Inspect in Chrome. A search in google and some reading led me to understand that what I see in Inspect is a stage called DOM which takes the raw html and runs some java scripts that add info and alter elements (go easy on me, I'm new at this ^_^).
Is there a why I can receive in GO the DOM instead of the raw html? I know I can use Chromedp, but I'm hoping for something more like some sort of an HTTP package because Chromedp a bit heavy on performance.
I would really appreciate any suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple HTTP request (via Go or anything else) will only ever get the raw HTML. The DOM is a browser-generated interpretation of the raw HTML. Yes, there is even something like the [Shadow DOM](https://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/).

JavaScript is interpreted by the browsers' JavaScript engine which applies changes to the DOM, adds event listeners and dynamically manipulates said DOM.

This is why you cannot get the DOM state you see in a browser through a HTTP request. The request does not contain all the client-side DOM manipulations done through a browsers' JavaScript engine. A request library is not a browser.

To get access to the full rendered DOM you're accustomed to see in the Developer Tools, you're going to need a more involved web scraping setup, usually involving a headless browser, like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer). However, this is written in Node.js. Given Go, you may have better luck with [chromedp](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp) or [cdp](https://github.com/mafredri/cdp).

Comment: Thank you! and one more small Q, when I "View Page Source", I basicly see the raw HTML? It would be identical to the HTTP requests' response?

Comment: If the server does not change the output for different user agents, then yes, it should be identical. Also, if you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: isn't there a html parser for go yet?

Comment: There certainly is (Example: https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery). However, like I mentioned, an HTML parser will **not** apply DOM manipulations made by JavaScript, which is what OP is apparently asking for.

Answer (score 0):

DOM stands for "Document Object Model", which is a tree of nodes where each node represents an element of the underlying document. Nodes may correspond to elements, text, comments, etc. There are many go-based DOM packages around. One you should look at is:

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html

It lets you parse HTML, and traverse elements of the document programatically.